# Gtk-WARNING related with themes, should I take them seriously?

Tags: unity, themes, gtk, evince

I launched `Evince` from the command prompt after `TexLive` installation to test some of generated pdf files and noticed that there were **warnings** related with `icon-themes`. While Evince was running I changed `icon-theme` settings within `Ubuntu Tweak` and noticed that some themes produced **warnings**, whereas some did not. I paste the output in the command prompt below. Let me state that I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit with Unity desktop environment. I appreciate any sight you can provide on this issue.

```
~$ evince sample2e.pdf

(evince:18251): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme file for Dust has no name


(evince:18251): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme file for Dust has no directories


(evince:18251): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme file for default has no name


(evince:18251): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme file for default has no directories


(evince:18251): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme file for ColoredPlastic has no name
```